# Editing a custom tab's text

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-tabactivity, android-tabs

I have a `Tab` that has a custom layout which contains a `TextView`.
I will need to later update that text from the actual tab child.

Here's how I set it up in the `TabActivity`

```
    private void setupTab(final String tag) {

//Call createTabView() to give the tab a layout with some text
        View tabview = createTabView(mTabHost.getContext(), tag);

        Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(this, MyActivity.class);
        TabSpec setContent = mTabHost.newTabSpec(tag).setIndicator(tabview).setContent(intent);

        mTabHost.addTab(setContent);
        mTabList.add(setContent);

    }


    private View createTabView(final Context context, final String text) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tabs_bg, null);
            TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tabsText);
            tv.setText(text); //we set the text of the tab here.

            LinearLayout tvX = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabsLayout);

            return view;
        }
```

So there is how I set it up... Now, in the child tab's activity I need it to update the text... I think the following would work if I didn't have custom tabs...

```
((TabActivity)getParent()).getTabHost().setTag(((TabActivity)getParent()).getTabHost().getCurrentTab(), "new text");
```

But I need custom tabs :)

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK i got it figured out!

In the `TabActivity` I have this method:

```
protected void updateText(int key, String text) {
    View view = mTabHost.getCurrentTabView();
    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tabsText);
    tv.setText(text);       
}
```

And then in my child tab I call this:

```
((MyTabActivity)getParent()).updateText(((TabActivity)getParent()).getTabHost().getCurrentTab(), "The new text");
```

And now you know :)